# How to implement iron-session with session id

Tags: next.js, session-cookies, next-connect

I am using iron-session, next-connect with nextjs in our webapp and one of the requirements is to publish analytics events from our frontend code, like page views, button clicks and other custom events. These events are stored in our database and used by our data analyst with PowerBI.

Our webapp takes a user on an onboarding journey, then once it's done, we create an account for the user and redirects to dashboard. For the onboarding part, we don't have a user id yet while in the dashboard, we already do. However, we want to be able to track the user journey in the webapp so we need an identifier that is persisted throughout the whole journey. Thus, we think of a session id with the iron-session.

Now iron-session doesn't have a concept of session id, so I am trying to implement it myself. The session id will be our identifier of the user in our `events` table.

Here is the `withSession` middleware used with `next-connect`

```
import { getIronSession } from "iron-session";
import type { IncomingMessage } from "http";
import type { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

import appConfig from "@/backend/app.config";

export const sessionOptions = {
  password: appConfig.secret,
  cookieName: appConfig.cookies.sessionToken.name,
  cookieOptions: appConfig.cookies.sessionToken.options,
};

export async function withSession(
  req: IncomingMessage | NextApiRequest,
  res: any,
  next: any
) {
  const session = await getIronSession(req, res, sessionOptions);
  if (!session.id) session.id = nanoid(32);
  req.session = session;
  await req.session.save();
  return next();
}

declare module "iron-session" {
  interface IronSessionData {
    user?: { id: string };
    id: string;
  }
}
```

And a route that will use the middleware

```
const router = createRouter<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>()
  .use(...([withSession, withLogger, withTenant] as const))
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    // Authenticate user
    req.session.user = { id: userId };
    await req.session.save();
    return res.redirect("/");
  });

export default router.handler();
```

- Is this a correct implementation of the said requirement?
- Some libraries implement a kind of session.regenerate() when a user perform `signIn` and `signOut`. Do I need to implement it too? If I do, I will lose the identifier that persists throughout the whole user journey.

Answer (score 0):

- since you are using `typescript` first define the type of session object

  ```
  declare module "iron-session" {
    interface IronSessionData {
      nameOfSessionObject?: {
         // in your implementation you were creating req.user and req.id
         // you could overwrite the req properties
         user?: { id: string };
         // you can manually create on the server
         id: string;
    };
   }
  }
  ```
- create a wrapper session function

  ```
      export function withSession(handler: any) {
        return withIronSessionApiRoute(handler, {
          password: appConfig.secret,
          cookieName: appConfig.cookies.sessionToken.name,
          //  Said in another way, the browser will not send a cookie with the secure attribute set over an unencrypted HTTP request
          cookieOptions: appConfig.cookies.sessionToken.options,
      })}
  ```
- create the session object. you do not use `getIronSession` when creating a session.

you need that when you need to access to the session object in middleware

```
export default withSessio(
  async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    if (req.method === "GET") {
      try {
        const sessionObj={....}
        req.session.nameOfSessionObject={...sessionObj}
        await req.session.save();
        // whatever you want to return
        return res.json(sessionObj);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("error in verify post req", error);
        // 422 Unprocessable Entity
        res.status(422).send({ message: "Cannot create SESSION" });
      }
    } else if (req.method === "POST") {
    
      try {
         ..HANDLE POST HERE
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(422).send({ message: "Cannot generate a SESSION" });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Invalid api Route" });
    }
  }
);
```

- now you can import above handler and connect with `next-connect`